How to pass a axios response to a function
I try this code and get an infinite loop
request.jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export async function getCategories() {
    const [categories,setCategories]= useState();
    try {
       await useEffect(() => {
            axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/req/categories",).then(function (res) {
                const response = JSON.stringify(res.data)
                setCategories(response);
            });
    
            
   
    
        }, [])
            return categorias;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

item_new.jsx

import { getCategories } from ".request";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const [categorieSelect, setCategorieSelect] = useState();

getCategories().then(response => {
    
    try {
      const res = JSON.parse(response);
     
      setCategorieSelect(res)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
 console.log(categorieSelect)  // infinite loop
  })

I also try to put a useEffect and get this error

react-dom.development.js:15408  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.<



import { getCategories } from ".request";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const [categorieSelect, setCategorieSelect] = useState();

getCategories().then(response => {
    
    try {
      useEffect(()=>{   
      
       const res = JSON.parse(response);
       setCategorieSelect(res)

   },[])
   

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
 console.log(categorieSelect)  // infinite loop
  })


You've drastically over-complicated this.  I don't know what examples you're following, but it looks like you're trying to use every possible operation you know of in every function you write.  Don't.
If getCategories() makes an AJAX request and returns a response then just do that.  There's no reason to involve anything about React in this.  For example:
export async function getCategories() {
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/req/categories");
  return res.data;
}

Then use it in your React component to fetch data and assign that data to state:
const [categorieSelect, setCategorieSelect] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  getCategories().then(cat => setCategorieSelect(cat));
}, []);

This useEffect will execute once when the component first loads, due to its empty dependency array.

hi! i try this before and as i mention,, the useEffect code give me the follow error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:


You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

but the axios it work well both ways (yours and mine), and you are right, i over use code there so i simplify

@Sodro: Read what the error is telling you.  useEffect, or any hook, can only be used in the body of a component or in the body of another hook.  Wherever else you're using it is wrong.  Alternatively, though more rarely, you might have more than one copy of React in the same app.  If you do, that needs to be corrected.  But what you most certainly haven't done is exactly what this answer is suggesting.  Simplify what you've written, and only use the hooks in the body of the component.  If you've tried that, please update the question with a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.
